# C# NetworkStream wont throw exception

Tags: c#, exception, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am writing a simple **C# server and client**, but it doesn't throw an exception when the client is disconnected. It will continue reading from the client, thinking that the client is still there. It also no longer blocks when the client is gone. I expect it to throw an exception if the client is no longer available.

```
private TcpListener server;
private NetworkStream stream;
private TcpClient client;
private byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

server = new TcpListener (serverIp, _portNumber);
server.Start();

stream = client.GetStream();
```

//The part I want to throw exception when the client is gone but doesn't.

```
try
{
    stream.Read(buffer,0,1);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    #if (DEBUG)
    Debug.Log ("Failed Rading " + e.Message);
    #endif
    return 0; 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client goes away without notifying the server there is nothing you can do except timeout. The server has no way of finding out the fact that the client is gone.

You need to live with this fact. Set a timeout.

Comment: What time should I set the timeout?

Comment: Pick a good tradeoff between false positives and false negatives. Depends on the network and on how fast you need to detect a dropped  connection. Reasonable values are [1, 30] seconds in most cases. Also, understand that there is no other way to detect failed connections in all cases. Timeouts are the only possible catch-all solution.

Comment: Do you mind posting a code snippet of that? TcpClient and NetworkStream class both have the timeout functions. Which ones should I set?

Comment: Probably the one that TcpClient has. I don't know from the top of my head. It should be easy to research.

Comment: TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 3000; waits for client message for 3 seconds then continues running. It doesn't solve the problem that the server will still be waiting while client is disconnected.......

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx after 3sec a timeout exception will be raised. You can react to that by killing the connection (disposing the TcpClient). Why wouldn't that work? The program rpobably only continues running because you're swallowing exceptions. Now you know why that is a bad practice.

Comment: What you said throws an exception when the client is still connected and server doesn't receive anything if the timeout set is reached. It doesn't throw exception when the client is disconnected. I am not swallowing anything. Thanks for helping. It partially solved the problem. Now I can disconnect when it throws exception while connected.

Comment: What I'm trying to get across is that *there is no way* to find out about disconnects with certainty. A timeout is the best you can do. If someone plugs the cable how would you immediately know?!

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thanks for the help. I needed the answer you provided too.

Answer (score 0):

It should throw an exception when the connection is closed and there is no more data in the buffer to read. Apparently there is still data available. When the buffer and the connection is closed you should get an exception.
Also I see you read data 1 byte at the time. Why not first check if the connection is alive:

```
client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead)
```

check if there is data available to read and read the correct amount:

```
int available = client.Client.Available;
if(available > 0)
{
   var buffer = new byte[available];
   client.Read(buffer, 0, available);
}
```

Comment: if(server.Client.Availabe) sounds awesome but the Client.Available part is not defined anywhere. I got some error.

Comment: Available is not a useful value. If it returns 0 you don't know that there really is no data available. Also, you cannot reliably check for a broken connection in any way.

Comment: Did you include the sockets namespace? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Comment: I did. I only found tcpclient.available not server.Client.Available. 
Also,  tcpclient.available doesn't do anything. It seems like you have to send a message to the client to be able to determine if it is still connected or not.

Comment: I'm sorry I now see you're programming the client and server in the same location. In that case you have to call server.Server.Available to see if the server has data available or client.Client.Available to see if the client has data available.